# Overlaying texture onto STL loaded mesh

Tags: javascript, jquery, stl, three.js

I'm looking for an efficient method of overlaying a texture to cover a mesh. I'm not an expert, more a novice, when it comes to 3 dimensional mapping/objects. Below shows how I would like the end product to look.

[image: Image depicting the end result]

When attempting to apply texture with the following code, the end result looks similar to below. I have not done any UV mapping, I believe my answer may be lay here. As you can see from the below image it roughly takes the general shade of the picture but I get the impression that the texture is being drawn between each vertice of the model rather than across the entirity.

```
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var texture = textureLoader.load('resource/images/materials/Mahogany.jpg');

var STLLoader = new THREE.STLLoader();
STLLoader.load( 'test.stl', function ( geometry1 ) {
 var meshMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:texture});

 var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry1, meshMaterial );

 mesh.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
 mesh.position.set(5, 20, 80);
 scene.add(mesh);
});
```

[image]

The cube has the correct texturing, whereas my STL loaded mesh does not.

Please ignore the rotation of the object in the above picture, I will move to unioning my objects together once I have fixed my texturing issues.

Fairly new at asking questions on here so please do comment to help me expand my question if it's too general or not percise enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
THREE.MeshPhongMaterial()
```

instead of

```
THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()
```

`THREE.MeshPhongMaterial()` will wrap the material outside the object and we can get curved material as per the object.